# String indices must be integers

Tags: python, string

I am getting the following error:

> *string indices must be integers, not str*

How can I resolve this?  Here is the code:

```
    if args['params']['text'][:5] == '!temp':
        degreeChar = u'\u00b0'
        url = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=' + args['params']['text'][9:] + '&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=' + WeatherAPIkey
        json_obj = urllib.urlopen(url)
        data = json.load(json_obj)
        temp = int(data['data']['current_condition']['temp_C'])
        ws.send('5:::' + genMessage('chatMsg', channel, username, 'Temperature in ' + args['params']['text'][6:] + ': ' + temp + degreeChar + 'C'))
```

The error is on this line: `temp = int(data['data']['current_condition']['temp_C'])`
The API is here: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqDwP.png)

Comment: What do you have stored in `args`? Is it a list or a dictionary?

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback; there are many lines here using indexing with strings and we need *at the very least* a hint at which line is involved.

Comment: I think `args['params']` returns a string.

Comment: Also, showing us what is in `args` and `data`.

Comment: [Arg](http://pastebin.com/DUAULwda) Check this. And yea args['params'] returns a string

Comment: @CosminZoRR it's only a few lines, you should edit it into your question. And you're not giving us the full traceback. The traceback points to the specific line causing the error, and as you can imagine this is _extremely helpful_ for debugging.

Comment: The error is on this line: temp = int(data['data']['current_condition']['temp_C']). If I remove it everything is ok. I tried to use int(). but dont work..

Comment: what does data look like?

Comment: Here is an [image](http://i.imgur.com/wHEKTyz.png)

Comment: @CosminZoRR why can't you edit that into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data['data']['current_condition']`  returns a list so you need use:

```
 `data['data']['current_condition'][0]['temp_C']`
```

to access the dict inside the list.